# How to get a 2D array from Google Sheets with JavaScript for using in an external app?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have this code, it's just a webpage with some JavaScript for displaying data on a table. This is using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html).

So the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js"></script>
  
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>

<script>

    const dataSet = [
        ['Planning', 'Planning_2024', '2023-11-30', '2023-11-09'],
        ['Documents', 'francois', '2023-11-30', '2023-10-31'],
        ['Archives', 'pdf', '2023-11-30', '2022-03-31'],
    ];

    new DataTable('#example', {
    columns: [
        { title: 'Description et lien, par exemple' },
        { title: 'Nom du document' },
        { title: 'date entrée' },
        { title: 'date création' }
    ],
    data: dataSet
    });

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

This is working fine with this 'dataSet' 2D array. But I would like to get this 2D array from an external Google Sheets file. And I cannot find the way to do this… Would you please help ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need. You have to this two informations:

1. **YOUR_CLIENT_ID**: the client ID that you created when you authorized
   credentials for a web application.
2. **YOUR_API_KEY**: the API key that you created as a Prerequisite.

After, enjoy!

[Google Sheet JS information](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js)